# Show java stored blob png files on webpage

Tags: java, php, mysql, codeigniter, blob

I have a problem showing my blob png files.

So I run testcases in a java project and if the test fails, I take a screenshot.
Due to environment and policy issues, I have to store my image in blob in a mysql database. If I download this blob file, it is a .bin file, but if I rename it to .png, the image is correctly shown.

I want to show this image in a webpage where my testresults are shown.
For this, I've tried the thing I find the most:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $row->screenshot ).'"/>';
```

I'm unable to show this image on my webpage (php), it keeps on showing the binary file.
For my webpage, I've used codeigniter.

So, my code in the java project is:

```
File srcFiler = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); //Appium screenshot
InputStream Screenshot = new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(srcFiler));
Class.forName(myDriver);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, user, password);

String query = "insert into screenshots (screenshotimage)"
                + "values (?)";

PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setBlob(1, Screenshot);
preparedStmt.execute();
preparedStmt.close();
conn.close();
```

Comment: Well it might be useful to see how the image is stored in the first please as that may be very relevant

Comment: @RiggsFolly , I've updated with code, so I'm running tests on appium whereas it fails, it takes a screenshot and saves it in the mysql database and I want to show this image in a webpage through php. If I download the blob, it is a .bin file and when I rename it to .png, the image works and is complete. But when I want to show it in the webpage, the image is shown with all kinds of special chars.

Comment: Did you try to copy your binary image data from your BLOB and use one of the internets free BASE64 encode and display services to see, if the image will be displayed properly there ? ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, I was looking in the wrong place. 
But maybe good to know this is a correct solution.